# configure rails to use database on a network machine for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How do I confgure Rails to use a postgres database that's on a server on my local network for development? Is it something that can be done through the database.yml options? If so, how do I specify the ip address of the machine where the database is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### config/database.yml

```
development:
  url:  <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
  ...
```

or

```
development:
  url:  some_database_url
  ...
```